James Cagney in Statue of Liberty scene
I'm trying to identify an old black and white movie I saw when I was a young boy. 
I'm almost sure it featured James Cagney.
I think he'd escaped from prison and the final scene was a shot of him inside the torch of the Statue of Liberty hence symbolising his freedom. 
I'd be grateful if anyone could remember the film as I'd love to see it again.

Can you tell us around what year/decade you saw the movie? Do you have any idea of what year/decade you think the movie was released in?

Saboteur of Hitcock? Photos (article in French) there: http://www.dvdclassik.com/critique/cinquieme-colonne-hitchcock, but not starred with James Cagney (in the wanted list of actor but seems that did get the role).

@Larme - You should write that up as an answer.

Seems to be Saboteur of Hitchcock.
James Cagney was in the short lists for the role, but at the end didn't make it.
Here are some images from the last scene you remember with the Statue of Liberty.:

